# Is there any benefit to being top of the training scoreboards during the "Atlas" campaign mission?

Tags: call-of-duty-advanced-warfare

During the second mission of campaign mode, "Atlas", there is a section where you have to do a couple of training exercises - Firearms and Grenades - and a third optional exercise on the Sentry Drone. (I am not 100% sure there are not any other optional exercises hidden around the level)

Each of the exercise areas has a scoreboard somewhere near by. Depending on what score you get, you will be ranked on the scoreboard.

**Does your position on the scoreboard have any effect/benefit?**

One thing that I do know is that your score doesn't seem to carry over when you replay the mission. After I completed the game I went back to look for missed Intel and I noticed I wasn't any any of the scoreboards. I know for sure I was 1st on the Sentry Drone exercise (that was the only scoreboard I noticed on my first play through)

**Update:**

I know there are two related trophies/achievements to getting "Excellent" on Firearms and/or Grenades. But you do not need to be top to get "Excellent", and then there is also the query about the Sentry Drone training exercise.

**Update 2:**

I read somewhere (I forgot where now) that being top of the leader boards is required to open up another area later on in the level where you obtain one of the intels. I have obtained all intels, and I *was* top of all 3 at the time, but I cannot say for sure that the area wouldn't have been available anyway. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting "excellent" on the training mini game mission things for shooting range and equipment (drone exercise excluded) gets you an achievement for each one. As well as a comment from Gideon or Liona.

It does not have any affect on the campaign going forward.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, but it gives you an achievement/trophy.